# How to fetch HTML Input Button Id in a Model in ASP.Net MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a button id as " previewButton " in the Input HTML tag.

```
<button type="submit" id="previewButton"></span>Preview</button>
<button type="submit" id="submitButton"></span>Submit</button>
```

I need to fetch the Id = previewButton (or) submitButton in the Model.

```
public class MyTestViewModel : BaseModel
{
    public MyTestViewModel()
    {
        IsDateChanged = null;
        IsChanges = null;
    }

    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Determine the date has changed?")]
    public int? IsDateChanged { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Is there any changes?")]
    public int? IsChanges { get; set; }

    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime PersonDOB { get; set; }

 }
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var clickedButtonName = $(this).val();
        $("#clickedButton").val(clickedButtonName);
        $('#previewButton').trigger('submit');
    });
});
```

Controller :

```
  public ActionResult New(MyTestViewModel viewModel, string ClickedButton)
    {
        var vm = ClickedButton;
        return View(vm);
    }
```

How to fetch HTML Input Button Id in c# - Model or Controller?

Comment: Don't add incomplete code please. First add html form's complete code and the controller method where you are actually expecting the id value.

Answer (score 0):

You can give same `name` attribute value for both the buttons and give unique values for the `value` attribute.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("New", "Home"))
{
   <!-- Your other form input elements goes here -->

   <button type="submit"  value="preview" name="from">Preview </button>
   <button type="submit" value="submit" name="from">Submit </button>
}
```

When the form is submitted, it will send the clicked button value as well in the form data.

Now in your action method which handles your form submit, you can add another parameter with the **same name as the button name**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(MyTestViewModel viewModel,string from)
{
    // to do : use "from"
    // to do : return something
}
```

Or you can add a new property to your view model with the same name as the button name.

```
public class MyTestViewModel 
{
    // your existing properties goes here
    public string From { set;get;}
}
```

When the form is submitted, model binder will be able to map the button value name to this new property.

Comment: Whether HttpPost is on the controller (or) it has to be in t he model?

Comment: What in the controller ? The action method is in controller and HTML markup inside your view file.

Comment: @Shyju, I am not sure but there will be arisen confusion between which button value will be passed irrespective of the click.

Comment: I agree with Tanvir. I will have to fetch this is in the Model. We already have Required field attribute in the Model. Based on the HTML Input value, i will have decide Required (or) RequiredIf

Comment: It will be the clicked button value only.

Comment: how do i get html input id in the model class? not on the controller

Comment: Will you please elaborate your code and help us, please

Comment: Just add a `public string SubmitType {get;set;}` to your model and set the name of both buttons to `SubmitType` and it will be on your model when you submit the form

Comment: ^^^^. Model binder will be able to map the item from the submitted form data to your view model property. Make sure the property name matches with the input name.

Comment: @goofyui First add html form's complete code and the controller method where you are actually expecting the id value. I am giving you the right solution.

Comment: I will do that, please give me a min

Comment: @goofyui I have posted my answer. Please check it. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I added the  public string SubmitType { get; set; } in myviewmodel. How should i retrieve the Html Input Id. I am able to get it in JQuery

Comment: Why you need the Id ? Whatever value you set it to the `value` attribute of the button will be available in the property. ( Make sure your property name and input button's name matches).

Answer (score 0):

**Your form should be as follows:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("New", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {id="MyFormId"}))
{
   <input type="hidden" id="clickedButton" name="clickedButton" value="">

   <!-- Your other form input elements goes here -->
   <button type="button"  value="preview">Preview</button> // button type is button not submit
   <button type="button" value="submit">Submit</button> // button type is button not submit
}
```

**Then in the jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var clickedButtonName =  $(this).val();
        $("#clickedButton").val(clickedButtonName);
        $('#MyFormId').trigger('submit');
    });
});
```

**Then in the Controller Post method:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(MyTestViewModel viewModel,string clickedButton)
{
    // do the necessary staff here
}
```

Comment: this has to be in the model

Comment: Which one? clicked button value?

Comment: thanks for your help.. iam still working on it .. controller logic will not work for me. This is mainly Required, RequireIf validation

Comment: First tell me is `clickedButton` value passed to controller method?

Comment: Action Result syntax is not getting called from the button click event. I added the Jquery and method which you gave me in the controller

Comment: public ActionResult New(MyViewModel viewModel, string ClickedButton)
        {
            var vm = ClickedButton;
            return View(vm);
        }

Comment: will you please take a look on it. I just added all the details

Comment: Have you set your form element Id attributes value according to jQuery Code?

Comment: $('#previewButton').trigger('submit');    -> That is my Button Id. I dont have a form element id

Comment: No no! You got things completely wrong! Set a id attribute value to Html.BeginForm(). Then use it in jQuery to trigger submit.

Comment: Check my answer! Specially Html and jQuery. I have updated my answer to make it more clear for you.